# Date separator issue

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

I have the following code

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

It always gives me this output : "04.13.2011" instead of "04/13/2011". May I know why I am getting this weird issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're almost certainly in a culture where that's the default date separator. If you want to *force* `/` you can quote it in the format string:

```
string x = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

Comment: Wow! It did the trick Awesome! Jon but in my case I am storing the formats userwise like "MM/dd/yyyy" and for other it can be "dd/MM/yyyy", for other it can be "dd-MM-yyyy" . I am going to fetch that format of user from DB and will use this code DateTime.Now.ToString(UserFormatStoredInDB). How can I handle this situation?

Comment: @Rocky: Just quote any separator you want to use... put the quoted string in the database. The quoted version will work in any culture. Or you *could* always specify the invariant culture to use for formatting, as an alternative.

Comment: can you please let me know the code for this "Or you could always specify the invariant culture to use for formatting," ?

Comment: @Rocky Singh: `DateTime.Now.ToString(formatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This ensures that the underlying date and time values do not change when the data is read or written by users from different cultures.